# EF4.4 - doesn't recognize List navigation property

Tags: entity-framework-4, navigation

I am learning EF and I have a problem about navigations. I hope you guys can show me the path :)

When I run this code, EF shows this message:

> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1 Sis.Model.Ft1Cap300.get_Ft1Cap300l()'."

I really dont get where the problem is; I think my navigation properties are okay, but EF says it doesn't recognize Ft1Cap300.Ft1Cap300l properties.

I have 3 models entities. I'll post the clases and their configuration

```
public class Ft1Caratula
{
    [Key]
    public String EncuestaId { get; set; }
    public Int32 DistritoId { get; set; }       //fk
    public String Conglomerado { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public Int32 Area { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public Int32 NumHogar { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public Int32 TotHogar { get; set; }
    public Int32 TipoComunidad { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public String JefeNombres { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public String JefeApePat { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public String JefeApeMat { get; set; }
    public Int32 DirTipo { get; set; }
    public String DirDireccion { get; set; }
    public Nullable<Int32> Dir1 { get; set; }
    public String Obs { get; set; }
    public Int32 Idioma { get; set; }
    public String Idioma_o { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public DateTime Ent1Fecha { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public Int32 Ent1Res { get; set; }
    public String Ent1Res_o { get; set; }
    public String EncId { get; set; }           
    public DateTime EncFecha { get; set; }

    public virtual UbiDistrito Distrito { get; set; }
    public virtual SegTecnico Encuestador { get; set; }

    public virtual List<Ft1Cap100> Ft1Cap100 { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Ft1Cap300> Ft1Cap300 { get; set; }
}

public class Ft1Cap300
{
    public String EncuestaId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int P301 { get; set; }

    public virtual Ft1Caratula Ft1Caratula { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Ft1Cap300l> Ft1Cap300l { get; set; }
}

public class Ft1Cap300l
{
    public String EncuestaId { get; set; }
    public int NOrden { get; set; }
    public String P302 { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int P303 { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int P304 { get; set; }
    public String P305_1 { get; set; }
    public String P305_2 { get; set; }
    public String P305_3 { get; set; }

    public virtual Ft1Cap300 Ft1Cap300 { get; set; }
}

public class Ft1CaratulaConfiguracion : EntityTypeConfiguration<Ft1Caratula>
{
    public Ft1CaratulaConfiguracion()
    {
        ToTable("ft1caratula", "data");
        HasRequired(p => p.Encuestador).WithMany(l => l.Ft1Caratulas).HasForeignKey(p => p.EncId);
        HasRequired(p => p.Distrito).WithMany(l => l.Ft1Caratulas).HasForeignKey(p => p.DistritoId);
    }
}

public class Ft1Cap300Configuracion : EntityTypeConfiguration<Ft1Cap300>
{
    public Ft1Cap300Configuracion()
    {
        ToTable("ft1cap300", "data");
        HasKey(p => new { p.EncuestaId });
        HasRequired(p => p.Ft1Caratula).WithMany(l => l.Ft1Cap300).HasForeignKey(p => p.EncuestaId);

    }
}

public class Ft1Cap300lConfiguracion : EntityTypeConfiguration<Ft1Cap300l>
{
    public Ft1Cap300lConfiguracion()
    {
        ToTable("ft1cap300l", "data");
        HasKey(p => new { p.EncuestaId, p.NOrden });
        HasRequired(p => p.Ft1Cap300).WithMany(l => l.Ft1Cap300l).HasForeignKey(p => p.EncuestaId);
    }
}
```

I hope you can help me with this. I have the book "Programming EF: CodeFirst" as a guide.

Answer (score 0):

Your code currently has the following problems 
In

```
public class Ft1CaratulaConfiguracion : EntityTypeConfiguration<Ft1Caratula>
    {
        public Ft1CaratulaConfiguracion()
        {
            ToTable("ft1caratula", "data");
            HasRequired(p => p.Encuestador).WithMany(l => l.Ft1Caratulas).HasForeignKey(p => p.EncId);
            HasRequired(p => p.Distrito).WithMany(l => l.Ft1Caratulas).HasForeignKey(p => p.DistritoId);
        }
    }
```

the class Ft1Caratula does not have the properties `Encuestador` and `Distrito`.

Aditionally in

```
public virtual List<Ft1Cap100> Ft1Cap100 { get; set; }
```

You are using a property as a type. So you should be getting some compile time errors.

Comment: hmm i dont get it, acording the book, in a one-to-many relationship i have to make this --> public virtual List<Ft1Cap300l> Ft1Cap300l { get; set; }  on father class, and --> public virtual Ft1Cap300 Ft1Cap300 { get; set; } on child class.